# In Rails how can I change the display method of my drop down list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using Simple Forms in Rails 4.2.  I have the following date selector for birth dates on my form page.  I want to display the months in the selector drop down list in the following format, `1-January`,`2-February`,`3-March`... Instead of `January`,`February`,`March`.  How can I do this?

```
<%= f.input :birth_date, as: :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 15, end_year: Time.now.year - 75,
        order: [:month, :day, :year], default: nil, label: false, include_blank: true,
        input_html: { style: 'margin: 15px 0px; display: inline-block; width: 110px;' } %>
```

Comment: You don't want the year to get displayed in the form?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, right now it displays the month, day, and year drop down lists. I just want the text in the month box to be prefixed by the number of the month.

Comment: add the option `month_format_string:  "%<number>02d-%{name}"`, it will work.

Comment: or add `add_month_numbers: true` option.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @ArupRakshit, if you submit an answer I'll confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you are looking for by applying either of the 2 options:

1. `add_month_numbers: true`
2. `month_format_string: "%<number>02d-%{name}"`